# RoR : staying logged before test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, factory-bot

I'm trying to run some tests on Ruby on Rails, but I don't know how to stay logged when testing. I tried :

```
  setup do
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
  end
```

But I get an error (duplicate), because it's running before EACH tests.

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests

How can I do for be logged only once in all tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this as a comment but couldn't get formatting on it so put it here.

Why do you want to log in only once for all the tests?
In theory, the point of isolated testing is to have each unit run as if it were a single interaction.

If you wanted to call something a single time, before the entire suite, you could put it in the spec helper:

```
config.before(:suite) do
   # Do Something Once
end
```

Are you talking feature specs?  Models?  Controllers?

But looking at what you posted it appears that you are probably talking about a feature spec, in which case, I would say do not do that.  Let the user login for each spec.

Side Note:
Noticing the error you have, you need to make sure you clean your DB before you run each spec.  Check out [Database Cleaner Gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) for this.  This will allow you to have that user recreated for each spec.